# SQL select values from a column by different ids that all have this value

Tags: mysql, select, join, group-by, self-join

let me explain my problem:
I have a table that contains product_id's and corresponding calender_week_id's for the possible delivery calender week. Each product can be delivered in multiple weeks:

```
| product_id | calender_week_id |    
| 1          | 1                |    
| 1          | 2                |    
| 2          | 1                |    
| 3          | 1                |    
| 3          | 2                |
```

...

What i now want are the calender_week_id's that match a set of product_id's (an order). Let's say I have product_id IN (1,2,3). Now I need an SQL statement that gives me all the calender_week_id's that match all the given product_id's - so in this case = 1 because calender_week_id = 1 is an corresponding value for product_id = 1, product_id = 2 and product_id = 3.

I hope you understand my problem and can help me!

Comment: Use ALL() instead of IN()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a query like the following:

```
SELECT calendar_week_id
FROM mytable
WHERE product_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY calendar_week_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) = 3;
```

The query returns `calendar_week_id` values related to *all distinct* `product_id` values specified in the `WHERE` clause.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/ZAML41180)